# aws-sdk-cpp undefined type Aws::Glacier::Model::GetDataRetrievalPolicyOutcome

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services

I use VS 2015 and aws-sdk-cpp 1.1.16 (version of Core) obtained via NuGet.
When I try to compile my program I get the following error:
`Error  C2027   use of undefined type 'Aws::Utils::Outcome<Aws::Glacier::Model::GetDataRetrievalPolicyResult,Aws::Client::AWSError<Aws::Glacier::GlacierErrors>>'`

This is my code:

main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int main()
{
    Aws::SDKOptions options;
    Aws::InitAPI(options);
    {
        Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration config;
        config.scheme = Aws::Http::Scheme::HTTPS;
        config.connectTimeoutMs = 30000;
        config.requestTimeoutMs = 30000;
        config.region = Aws::String(Aws::Region::EU_WEST_1);

        Aws::Glacier::GlacierClient client(config);
        Aws::Glacier::Model::GetDataRetrievalPolicyRequest request;
        Aws::Glacier::Model::GetDataRetrievalPolicyOutcome outcome = client.GetDataRetrievalPolicy(request);
        //^^^ error at this line
        if (outcome.IsSuccess()) {
            Aws::Vector<Aws::Glacier::Model::DataRetrievalRule> rules = outcome.GetResult().GetPolicy().GetRules();
            for (auto it : rules) {
                std::cout << it.GetStrategy() << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "GetDataRetrievalPolicy error: "
                << outcome.GetError().GetExceptionName() << std::endl
                << outcome.GetError().GetMessage() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    Aws::ShutdownAPI(options);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

stdafx.h

```
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <aws/acm/ACMClient.h>
#include <aws/core/Aws.h>
#include <aws/core/Region.h>
#include <aws/core/client/ClientConfiguration.h>
#include <aws/core/client/AWSClient.h>
#include <aws/glacier/GlacierClient.h>
#include <aws/glacier/model/GetDataRetrievalPolicyRequest.h>
#include <aws/glacier/model/GetDataRetrievalPolicyResult.h>
#include <aws/glacier/model/DataRetrievalPolicy.h>
#include <aws/glacier/model/DataRetrievalRule.h>
```

I've tried to replace `Aws::Glacier::Model::GetDataRetrievalPolicyOutcome` with `auto` or `Aws::Utils::Outcome<type_of_result, type_of_error>` but this did not help

P.S. Also i can't create any instance of `Aws::Utils::Outcome<R,E>` with any types

P.P.S. And when i trying to include `#include <aws/core/utils/Outcome.h>` i get the following errors:
`Error  C2535   'Aws::Utils::Outcome<std::string,std::string>::Outcome(R &&)': member function already defined or declared  ..\packages\awssdkcpp-core.1.1.16\build\native\include\aws\core\utils\outcome.h 50

Error   C2535   'Aws::Utils::Outcome<std::string,std::string>::Outcome(const R &)': member function already defined or declared ..\packages\awssdkcpp-core.1.1.16\build\native\include\aws\core\utils\outcome.h 44`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, when i changed stdafx.h to

```
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <aws/core/Aws.h>
#include <aws/glacier/GlacierClient.h>
#include <aws/glacier/model/GetDataRetrievalPolicyRequest.h>
#include <aws/core/utils/Outcome.h>
```

Everything started to work